# How to output encode a hidden field in jsp using spring escapeBody tag

Tags: spring, jsp, character-encoding

I am trying to use the `<spring:escapeBody>` for a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="displayId" id="displayId" value="${displayIdValue}"/>
```

I tried adding the `<spring:escapeBody>` around the value field, as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="displayId" id="displayId" value=<spring:escapeBody>"${displayIdValue}"</spring:escapeBody>/>
```

but it gives a syntax error. what is the right syntax. I have looked online but couldn't find it.

Comment: What is the actual and expected outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use spring tags  instead as it provides the required output encoding.